# How do I remove offset from output of a binary file in Go?

Tags: go, binaryfiles

I'm trying to only print out the data from a binary file in Go. None of the offset. Here's what I have for printing it out:

```
func readBinaryFile(filename string) {

    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    defer file.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(file)

    buf := make([]byte, 256)

    for {
        _, err := reader.Read(buf)

        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s", hex.Dump(buf))
    }

}

func main() {

    filename := os.Args[1]

    readBinaryFile(filename)

}
```

how do i remove all the offset it prints? I've tried a thousand things.

here's an example of output:
[image: example]

Comment: What offset? What specifically is it you're trying to remove?

Comment: Each offset is an integer (4 bytes) that gives the
offset from the start of the file to the start of each line (the next section)

Comment: so when you print the binary file the way I have it, it prints out a bunch of numbers along with the string data. i just want the string data in the file

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you're getting?

Comment: i put it in the post

Comment: i think maybe what i'm trying to say is parse the file?

Comment: That's the format that `hex.Dump()` prints (according to the documentation, it's the same as the output of the command `hexdump -C`). If you want to print the output in a different format, you'll have to write your own code to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question which output you are looking for:

1. [`hex.Dump`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex#Dump) format without the offset, or
2. Only print hex output

Assuming you only want to strip the offset from the dump, I would process the output:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)   

func main() {
    buf, _ := io.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
    dump := hex.Dump(buf)
    fmt.Print(stripOffset(dump))
}   

func stripOffset(dump string) string {
    var b strings.Builder
    for dump != "" {
        var line string
        line, dump = next(dump, "\n")
        _, afterOffset := next(line, "  ")
        b.WriteString(afterOffset)
    }
    return b.String()
}

func next(s string, end string) (string, string) {
    if i := strings.Index(s, end); i >= 0 {
        split := i + len(end)
        return s[:split], s[split:]
    }   
    return s, ""
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
$ echo some string to test the output | ./hex 
73 6f 6d 65 20 73 74 72  69 6e 67 20 74 6f 20 74  |some string to t|
65 73 74 20 74 68 65 20  6f 75 74 70 75 74 0a     |est the output.|
```

Alternatively, use [`hex.EncodeToString`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex#EncodeToString) for just the hex output:

```golang
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(buf))
```

```
736f6d6520737472696e6720746f207465737420746865206f75747075740a
```

Or format via [`fmt.Printf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Printf):

```golang
fmt.Printf("% 02x\n", buf)
```

```
73 6f 6d 65 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67 20 74 6f 20 74 65 73 74 20 74 68 65 20 6f 75 74 70 75 74 0a
```